# Smarty Cache undefined index error prestashop

Tags: caching, smarty, prestashop

Notice on line 349 in file

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sunrayzz\cache\smarty\compile\b3\28\62\b3286241c53ed18bb03074a03880792b750ec66b.file.form.tpl.php
[8] Undefined index: label
```

Notice on line 600 in file

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sunrayzz\cache\smarty\compile\b3\28\62\b3286241c53ed18bb03074a03880792b750ec66b.file.form.tpl.php
[8] Undefined index: page_item
```

**I Keep getting this errors. even I turned off my compile in Performance in back office. Please help.**

Comment: Those are notices, not errors Also, you don't say what prestashop version are you using. Please, try to be more verbose about your problem: it's a new installation?, when does it happen?, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This notices are being generated when there are undefined variables in templates. Check the file from the specified location and see which is the original template.

You can suppress this with:

```
{if isset($label)}
...
{/if}
```

etc...

Answer (score -1):

I solve the same error by cleaning the cache from the backoffice
(Adavanced settings -> Performance).